# Parameterise expect script

Tags: bash, expect

I have a script that interacts with some heating controls via tellnet

```
1 | #!/usr/bin/expect
2 | set timeout 10
3 | set ip [lindex $argv 0];
4 | set port [lindex $argv 1];
5 | log_file [lindex $argv 2];
6 | spawn telnet $ip $port
7 | expect "'^]'." 
8 | sleep .1
9 | send "{\"INFO\":0}\0\r"
10| expect "}]}"
11| send "\35"
12| expect "telnet>"
13| send "q\r"
14| interact
```

This works fine but I want to parameterise line 9 but despite my best efforts I cant make it work. It must be down to how the escaping is working.

Ideally my new script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set ip [lindex $argv 0];
set port [lindex $argv 1];
log_file [lindex $argv 2];
set command [lindex $argv 3];
send_user $command;
spawn telnet $ip $port
expect "'^]'." 
sleep .1
send "$command"
expect "}]}"
sleep .1
send "\35"
expect "telnet>"
send "q\r"
interact
```

and I would call it from a bash script like:

```
BASE_PATH=/usr/share/testing
LOG=$BASE_PATH/telnet.log
IP=10.10.10.5
PORT=4242
COMMAND="{\\\"INFO\\\":0}\0\r"

A_TEMP=`$BASE_PATH/telnet.sh $IP $PORT $LOG "$COMMAND"` 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you have commented the `expect` statement post sending the command ? Remove the comment and have that in your code as

```
send "$command"
expect "}]}"
```

After sending a command, we should always `expect` for something. Else, `Expect` does not wait for that. We have to make it wait explicitly. If still problem persists, add `-d` flag with expect and post the debug info.

By the way, when you say it is not working , what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: sorry the # was posted by mistake.

Comment: Ok. How about debug info? Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the quotes on the `send` command that uses the variable, like this:

```
...
send $command
...
```